# JSON html parse

Tags: html, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse some json from html but I can't get my head around the

the code i've tried to use is:

```
article = [[jsonDict valueForKey:@"<divid= fb_share_1 style="";"]valueForKey :@"posts"];

cell.textLabel.text = [[article objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
```

this is the json

```
 <divid="fb_share_1"style="float:left; margin-left: 10px;;"name="fb_share"><divid="fb-root"></div><scriptsrc="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=125029517579627&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb: likehref="http://universitytimes.ie/?p=23421"send=""layout="button_count"show_faces="false"font="arial"></fb: like></div>p=23297"send=""layout="button_count"show_faces="false"font="arial"></fb: like></div>{
  "status": "ok",
  "count": 10,
  "count_total": 2448,
  "pages": 245,
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 23421,
      "type": "post",
      "title": "Coppers accident"
}

]
```

thanks for the help in advance

Comment: I've fixed up your formatting, but your JSON seems incomplete.

Comment: thanks!the is too big so i only took a small part of it.